# empty activity shown before fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments

when starting the application the main Activity is charging first showing an empty screen then charging the fragment.
here the MainActivity's onCreate methode.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_starting_activity);
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        switchFragment(FragmentOne.instanciate(0));

}
```

after charging this activity the fragment in shown!

the question is how to load the fragment the same time as the activity??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you have setcontentview for your mainactivity it is displaying layout_starting_activity and then your fragment. remove setcontentview from your oncreate and try again.

Note: if your activity has fragment which is full screen size and there is nothing your main activity layout displays you don't really need to set layout for your main activity it usually display fragments layout once activity is created.

If my answer is not clear please post more code I will be able to help.